# GetWindowText and GetWindowTextLength running without parenthesis?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Examining this piece of code, with buffer being declared as LPWSTR and using Visual Studio 2010:

```
        buffer = (LPWSTR)GetWindowText;
        int x = GetWindowTextLength(hDlg);
```

This compiles and runs just fine (other than I have to figure out how to process the string to make it readable), but what's more, for at least these two functions, the compiler accepts them either with an appropriate cast, or with their parameters, why does it accept them without parentheses? I haven't seen something similar, any Clues?

Comment: What on earth is `(LPWSTR)GetWindowText` supposed to be? You're casting a function (pointer) to a `wchar_t *`. Keep in mind said function does not return the string, either.

Comment: `(LPWSTR)GetWindowText` appears to be a function pointer

Comment: a) I've seen it done around
b) I'm casting the result to the format I want it
c) I've got no idea why the compiler accepts it, and that's why I am asking why this runs without an error

Comment: So I'm casting a pointer? apparently not my initial intent... Sounds reasonable though, as these functions are replaced with the appropriate version to fit the encoding used as far as I know, so yeah, a pointer would do the job for that...

Comment: For the record, I'm somewhere between learning how to retrieve text from an editable text box in a dialog box, and just experimenting with whatever function I find.

Comment: With the exception of casts in a class hierarchy and from/to void*, if you are using a cast on pointers it's very likely you are doing something wrong. In this case *really* wrong.

Comment: The fact that compiler accepts it does not mean it's usable or helpful. The code makes sense to compiler, not to you; does not help you to fulfill any reasonable task.

Comment: Reasonable you say ? Casting the address of a function into a wide string pointer ? The function is not even called ! This... is... just... wrong... The pointer in question points at executable code... why would that memory area ever contain an exploitable wide string ?

Comment: @user3079666, No casts are needed (or desired). If you'd read the documentation, it would be plain to see that the function takes the buffer as a parameter and returns an `int` - the number of characters copied.

Comment: I propose you grab your favorite C primer, lean back and read about (at least) "Function Pointers" and "Casting".

Comment: Ok, got it, still, if I had not come across this nonsense I wouldn't have known that, so turns out to be good for me. Thanks everybody :)

Comment: @user3079666: one suggestion: don't try to learn Win32 (or C++) by random experimentation, you are going to hurt yourself badly and pick up terrible habits. I had a quick look at your WinAPI tutorial and I find that there are several misconceptions. You should really start with a good book, a classic is Petzold's Programming Windows (5th edition, the 6th edition is about C# and Metro UI).

Comment: Also, get a good grasp of C++ before Win32 or it's just more pain, such as this. This code really has little to do with Win32. It's like doing `(char *)fgets;` or `(std::string)std::getline;`.

Comment: I've got a couple of books, I made a small game with the GDI a few months ago and I'm trying to get a more complete idea, experimentation refers to jumping into the Win32Api Superbible and trying out functions, or just modifying existing code, I've got it under control, but thanks anyway.
Programming Windows 5th edition is in my list, came across it just yesterday, but I've got a couple more books around :)

Answer (score 4):

When a function name is used in expressions like this

```
buffer = (LPWSTR)GetWindowText;
```

then there is used its address that is the primary expression is converted to a pointer to the function.

Comment: So this is just the pointer, it doesn't run the function..

Comment: @user3079666 Yes, it is just a pointer that is casted to LPWSTR.

Comment: Ok, it didn't occur to me that this is how you call function pointers. Thanks!

Comment: This is not how you call function pointers. This is how you assign them to something. The name of a function, without parentheses, is a function pointer.

Comment: @Vlad You really ought to have pointed out that the cast is utterly bogus.

Comment: I think that it became very obvious, I mean, a cast is supposed to turn one form of something that makes sense into another, so since this does not make any short of sense, there is no point on casting, unless I am missing even more.

Comment: @user3079666 You may not assign the function pointer to buffer without casting because as it seems the buffer has type LPWSTR.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: You can't assign a **function pointer** to a **text buffer** to begin with. A function pointer does not return text.  Without the parenthesis to actually call the function, there is no text being returned. It is just a pointer to a function, plain and simple.  The buffer can't do anything with it. You need to call the function and copy the returned text into the buffer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I know, that's why I cast in the first place

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you can cast anything to anything (more or less), it's all 0s and 1s to the compiler, it just is pointless, isn't that what you mean?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: a function pointer that is type-casted to a text pointer is MEANINGLESS.  It is not real text. If you have to resort to such a type-cast, you are doing something VERY wrong in your code. The *correct* way to handle this situation is to call `GetWindowTextLength()` first to get the window's text length, then ALLOCATE a text buffer of that length, and finally call `GetWindowText()` to FILL the buffer with the window's text.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau I have no any reasons. I only speak about the code that can be compiled because I do not know the constext where it is used.